# Nested Resource ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using ActiveAdmin and attempting to do a very simple nested form. I have reviewed a lot of answers to similar questions that don't work.

Below I've created a form that only includes one field called dba_number of the business model.

I get the following error when I attempt to save a new Address

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: business

I've read a lot about this security feature and even reviewed Ryan Bates's nested form tutorial. I can't see anything else to change with this.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm missing?

Here is my code

```
#app/models/business.rb

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :dba_number, :name, :industry_id, :address_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :owners
  belongs_to :industry
  belongs_to :address
  end
end

#app/models/address.rb

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :street_number, :post_office_box_number, :apartment_number, :street_name, :street_suffix_id, :city, :zip_code, :state_id, :businesses_attributes, :permits_attributes
  validates_presence_of :city, :zip_code
  has_many :owners
  has_many :businesses
  has_many :permits
  belongs_to :street_suffix
  belongs_to :state
end

#admin/addresses.rb file

ActiveAdmin.register Address do

  form :partial => 'form'

  controller do
    def new
      new! do |format|
        @address = Address.new
      end
    end

    def create
      create! do |format|
        address = Menu.find(params[:address])
        if @address.save
          redirect_to {admin_address_url}
        end
      end
    end
  end

end

app/views/admin/addresses/_form.html.erb

<%= semantic_nested_form_for [:admin, @address] do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs "Details" do %>
      <%= f.input :street_number %>
      <%= f.input :post_office_box_number %>
      <%= f.input :apartment_number %>
      <%= f.input :street_name %>
      <%= f.input :street_suffix , :as => :select, :collection => Hash[StreetSuffix.all.map{|a| [a.suffix_name, a.id]}] %>
      <%= f.input :state, :as => :select, :collection => Hash[State.all.map{|s| [s.abbr, s.id]}] %>
      <%= f.input :city %>
      <%= f.input :zip_code %>
      <%= f.inputs :dba_number, :for => :business, :name => "Business" %>

<% end %>
    <%= f.actions %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add following code to models/address.rb or Rails will think businesses is attribute of businesses

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :businesses
```

reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

or maybe problem happen at

```
<%= f.inputs :dba_number, :for => :business, :name => "Business" %>
```

You changed the input default name(like model['attribute']) to be 'Business'.
try to not to set name

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence  "You changed the input default name(like model['attribute']) to be 'Business'. try to not to set name
"

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, I mean that the dba_number input will automatically be named address['dba_number'], and you override it to be 'Business' so if you use params[:address] may not work